# Does RPM build always take the files from ~/rpmbuild?

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

Everywhere I have seen on the internet, the default location for the rpmbuild is a user's home directory, `~/rpmbuild`. What if I wish to build it in another folder location, say, `~/foo/bar/rpmbuild`?

Why is this? What difference would it make if my build location is something else?

EDIT: This means even the `~/rpmmacros` file could be anywhere.

Comment: Please see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/need-rpm-package-for-php-version-5-2-7-and-up-on-redhat-5-1-a-766486/#13 ... for the setup. You can change those locations to your preferred location. And you can use $ `rpmbuild -bb file.spec` in any folder. The packages will be created to the folder specified in .rpmmacros .

Comment: I understand. I guess what I meant was, even moving the ~/.rpmmacros file to another location and have the rpmbuild pick it up from there? Is there no way? Or is it that this configuration does not matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build rpms without having to modify or maintain a .rpmmacros file by specifying _topdir in the rpmbuild command line. For example,

```
rpmbuild --define '_topdir $(RPMBUILD_DIR)' \
    --define 'version $(VERSION)' \
    --define 'release $(RELEASE)' \
    -bb $(PKGNAME).spec
```

is in one of my Makefiles for an rpm project to build my rpms under ${RPMBUILD_DIR} with the specified version and release numbers from variables. I use this a lot so that I can have multiple rpm-building projects that don't conflict with each other trying to build in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the `%_topdir` variable in the `.rpmmacros` configuration file (in your home directory) like this:

```
echo "%_topdir ~/foo/bar/rpmbuild" >> ~/.rpmmacros
```

It wouldn't (shouldn't) really make much difference; since sources are to be copied there by `rpmbuild`; then they are build and installed and packaged... Since all paths are supposed to be relative the outcome should be the same.

PS: more information on the [rpm build area](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-anywhere-different-build-area.html)
PPS: a long time ago the default `build area` was in /usr/src/packages ; but then you had permission issues etc.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear earlier. Please refer to my comment under the question.

Comment: rpm --macros /colon:/separated:paths is one way to relocate what macro files are read. There is also an ancient way to override the macro paths from within an rpmrc file that may still function with rpm.org code (rpm5.org has mostly abandoned rpmrc files as a means of configuration as too complicated).